# Set global variable inside async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function that should list the strings of available games into the `activeGames` array. When I log the array it returns empty, however, if I set a 1 second time out it will log correctly. Why is this happening?

```js
let activeGames = []

const getActiveGames = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(someUrl)
  const data = await res.json()

  const list = data.content.filter(game => (
    game.aggregatorId === 'someString'
  ))

  activeGames = list.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (!a.includes(c)) {
      return [...a, c.gameId]
    } 
  }, [])
}

getActiveGames()

console.log(activeGames);
// []
```

Comment: You do not await the getActiveGames call

Comment: Don't use global variables. You never know when they get written. Just move the `console.log` statement inside your function where you computed the `activeGames`!